# ng-model not updating AngularJS

Tags: angularjs

So i have this html. The issues is that is changing the model(filter) when i select one of those that i have create in a static way but the dynamic ones does not trigger the change of the value. Any ideas?

Thanks.

```
<div class="row">
        <div class="col-xs-6">
            <h3>Group 1</h3>
            <hr>
            <div class="checkbox">
                <input type="radio" name="filterGroup" ng-model="filter" ng-value="5"><label>5</label>
            </div>
            <div class="checkbox">
                <input type="radio" name="filterGroup" ng-model="filter" ng-value="4'"><label>4</label>
            </div>
        </div>
        <div class="col-xs-6">
            <h3>Group 2</h3>
            <hr>
            <div class="checkbox">
                <input type="radio" name="filterGroup" ng-model="filter" ng-value="3"><label>3</label>
            </div>
            <div class="checkbox">
                <input type="radio" name="filterGroup" ng-model="filter" ng-value="2'"><label>2</label>
            </div>
            <div class="checkbox">
                <input type="radio" name="filterGroup" ng-model="filter" ng-value="1"><label>1</label>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
    <div class="row">
        <div class="col-xs-6">
            <h3>DinamicItems</h3>
            <hr>
            <div class="checkbox" ng-repeat="item in items">
                <input type="radio" name="filterGroup" ng-model="filter" ng-value="'{{item.value}}'"><label>{{item.text}}</label>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
```

Comment: it's because you are breaking the rule of always using an object in `ng-model`. Using `ng-repeat` creates child scopes and therefore you break 2 way binding when using a primitive

Answer (score 2):

What Charlie is saying is, your model of *tag* is a primitive one. Each instance of ng-repeat creates it's own scope. Therefore, your models, although named 'tag', are not in fact the same.

To remedy, you should make your model something like *vm.tags* (vm = view model.)

A few things to read up on, and learn more:

- Controller As: https://johnpapa.net/angularjss-controller-as-and-the-vm-variable/
- ng-repeat: https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/directive/ngRepeat
- Understanding Scopes https://github.com/angular/angular.js/wiki/Understanding-Scopes (When I was getting started with Angular, I had to read through this a few times, and still do on occasion)

Comment: i resolve it by adding ng-click and updating the model in a function. Thanks